# C# .Net Entity Framework 6 change DbSet<model class> to List<List<Object>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a project that I am using to learn about EF6. I started the project and setup a database first model. There are a couple of existing tables and views.  The result includes "classes" that represent the table / view db structures.  My eventual goal is to populate Excel workbook sheets with the results.

I can access and sort, etc, the `DbSet` data that is returned a la:

```
using (var db = new TestDbEntities()) {
    var list = db.TestTable1s
                 .OrderBy(m => m.machine.ToUpper())
                 .ThenBy(m => m.netid.ToUpper())
                 .ToList<TestTable1>();

    var columnNames =
            (from t in typeof(TestTable1).GetProperties()
            select t.Name)
            .ToList<string>();
}
```

However, I am stuck when it comes to getting the column data values. For example, if I add a loop at the bottom of the `using` above:

```
    var row = 1;

    foreach (var line in list) {
        var col = 1;

        if (row == 1) {
            //
            // print table headers
            foreach (var item in columnNames) {
                cells[row, col++].Value2(item);
            }

            col = 1;
        }

        //
        // print table "body"
        foreach (var item in line) {
            cells[row, col++].Value2(item);
        }

        row++;
    }
```

In the "body" loop `item` is an instance of type `TestTable1`. I am told by visual studio that `TestTable1` is not enumerable.

So my question is, how do I access the members of class `TestTable1` in a list-like way? Should I just access each known member as `item.memberName`?

Comment: *Should I just access each known member as item.memberName?* Shortly, yes. And this for any C# class, has nothing to do with EF.

Comment: Well you're already using reflection so you don't need to do `item.memberName`

Comment: DavidG can you expand on that?

Comment: Well if you already know the type you are using (`TestTable1`) then you don't need to think about that, just use `item.memberName`

Answer (score 1):

The first list created in your code is the collection of the entities retrieved from the db. And you can loop thru it to create table like structure in the ui.

In fact you can bind this collection to datagridview or datagrid to show the data in tabular format. You just need to know how to use those controls.

If columns in your table are not going to change very frequently then this is the approach you should take.